# Notation question: characteristic subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, notation

The definition included that $f(H)=H$.

This does not mean $\forall x\in H | f(x)=x$ right? Or not?!

Comment: this means that $ \forall x\in H$ $f(x)=x'$ whith $x' \in H$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $f(H) = H$ means that the range of $f$ is $H$. Recall that

> $$f(H) = \{f(x) \mid x \in H\} $$

More concretely, it just means that $f$ takes an element of $H$ and moves it to another element of $H$, which may (and usually) is not the same.